# The linked-list add function in two ways get different result

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I achive  linked-list add  in two ways , but the `add1` was got a wrong result, I think `current is self.head` is True, but don't know way get this result

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,var=None):
        self.var=var
        self.next=None

class SingleList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.size=0

    def add1(self,var):
        p=Node(var)
        current=self.head
        p.next=current
        current=p

    def add2(self,var):
        p=Node(var)
        p.next=self.head
        self.head=p

if __name__ == "__main__":
    linked_list=SingleList()
    linked_list.add(1)
    linked_list.add(2)
```

The stack below:

[image]

[image]